# Convert "yyyymmddhhmiss" Text to DateTime

Tags: t-sql

We have a vendor database in which for some unknown reason all of the datetime values are actually nvarchar(14) in the format of "yyyymmddhhmiss". I have been hunting for a T-SQL function to do something like this....

```
FORMAT(TextDatetime, "yyyymmddhhmiss")
```

Unfortunately, it looks like [FORMAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) only takes numeric or date and time datatypes.

I could create user-defined scalar function like this...

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_Convert_TextDatetime
(
    @TextDateTime nvarchar(14)
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN DATETIMEFROMPARTS (
                                 SUBSTRING (@TextDateTime, 1, 4)
                               , SUBSTRING (@TextDateTime, 5, 2)
                               , SUBSTRING (@TextDateTime, 7, 2)
                               , SUBSTRING (@TextDateTime, 9, 2)
                               , SUBSTRING (@TextDateTime, 11, 2)
                               , SUBSTRING (@TextDateTime, 13, 2)
                               , '0'
                             )
END;
```

The volume of data in this database is small so I am not that concerned about performance.

Is this user-defined function the best solution here?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that utilizes [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to create a properly formatted [DATETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) value.

> The STUFF function inserts a string into another string. It deletes a
> specified length of characters in the first string at the start
> position and then inserts the second string into the first string at
> the start position.

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_Convert_TextDatetime
(
    @TextDateTime nvarchar(14)
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@TextDateTime,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-'),13,0,':'),16,0,':'),11,0,' ')
END;
```

**Input:**

| test_dt |
| --- |
| 20220914010101 |
| 20220915185700 |
| 20220916234559 |

```
SELECT dbo.udf_Convert_TextDatetime(test_dt) AS datetime FROM test
```

**Output:**

| datetime |
| --- |
| 2022-09-14 01:01:01.000 |
| 2022-09-15 18:57:00.000 |
| 2022-09-16 23:45:59.000 |

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/nx-pkuHZ).